# Browser says "Connecting" - pages not loading

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Lately I've been seeing the status message "Connecting" in Chrome's status bar while (several) websites were taking minutes to load, often resulting in a timeout error. With enough patience, the site will eventually load, but getting these delays randomly is starting to get on my nerves.

Since these symptoms can describe a wide number of possible causes, I've tried ruling out a few. Namely, the problem appears regardless of whether I:

- access one web domain or another; namely, the same domain can manifest this problem at one point, but load just fine the next day
- empty the browser's cache; I tried [this suggestion](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/empty-google-chrome-cache-fix-waiting-for-cache-error/) because the "Connecting" status message sometimes turns into "Waiting for cache"
- have my firewall (Comodo Premium Internet Security) or its AV component turned on or off
- turn the Windows Firewall on or off
- access websites through one browser or another (have tried Firefox and MS Edge in addition to Chrome)
- connect to the Internet via different WiFi networks (private router & public router)
- connect to the Internet through a WiFi or through an wired/Ethernet adaptor

I am using Windows 10. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Pings are ok to these trouble domains? Didn't see reboot the router in your bullet point. :)

Comment: You're right, that would have been one to try as well, but in my case I do't have direct access to the router so I cannot do it .. I'll check the ping next time it happens. For now I am trying to see if I get this problem when taking this PC (laptop) to another location with a different connection, as the problem might simply be with the network in the first location